# Getting error while trying to build with flutter_local_notification plugin in my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, gradle, error-handling

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
lib\main.dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\shibl\Desktop\project-3\myTodo\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:44:13-51:23: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

```
 C:\Users\shibl\Desktop\project-3\myTodo\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:52:12-109: AAPT: error: unexpected element <receiver> found in <manifest><application><activity>.
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin flutter_local_notifications...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_local_notifications-3.0.1+2\android\build.gradle' line: 22
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'flutter_local_notifications'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
> Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.6.4. Current version is 5.6.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_local_notifications-3.0.1+2\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.6.4-all.zip

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: The plugin flutter_local_notifications could not be built due to the issue above.
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same error, and I resolved it by placing the receiver syntax inside the application tag in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Can you explain the answer a bit?

Comment: could you please show how to add this receiver syntax, thnx in advance